# Can one store short text data when transacting ERC20 tokens?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-223

I am having trouble understanding if i can store short pieces of text when I send an ERC20 token. I have successfully stored a small message when transacting ETH by converting it to HEX and adding it to the "data" section in MEW. However, the "data" section when sending a custom ERC20 token doesn't work. Why is that?

To give you a clearer picture, we are building a social platform in NYC, called The Jesuit Token, where people are rewarded tokens for every hour of community service performed. Every time we issue new tokens, we are looking to add a little bit of text data to the transaction summarizing what kind of community service the person performed to receive a token. The idea is to have the information broadcasted on the network for transparency reasons and for later analysis of the social impact people have.

I would really appreciate if anyone a little more technically inclined could help us out. Remember, this is a promising social platform and you might impact the lives of many people by helping it launch! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still designing the ERC20-compliant contract, or is it an already deployed standard ERC20 token that you cannot alter?